# Button in hyperlink style

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Hello friends can you tell me how to make style of button like hyperlink.
I want to add Hyperlink to the GridView but Hyperlink has not Click event. I decided to use button, but make it appearence like hyperlink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CssClass="linkBtn">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

with the class `linkBtn` like this one:

```
.linkBtn {
            border: none;
        }
```

And it looks like the same as HyperLink ^^

Comment: Hyperlink do not have CommandName. so how can fire GridView_RowCommand() event?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `LinkButton`. LinkButton has `on click` event or can use CommandName.

Answer (score 0):

In GridView, Edit Column options, uncheck auto-generate columns, add the columns you want and use template field.
Edit template and use Link Button there.

Also use `GridView1_RowCommand()` event for that Link Button.